# SVG animation with GSAP

Tags: javascript, svg, gsap

I might be missing something simple, but I can not animate SVG elements with GSAP despite the animations working well with HTML.

For example, if I have two circles — one created with HTML/CSS, the other with SVG — the HTML element gets animated while the SVG one does not:

```js
var circle = document.getElementById("html"); // Does work
var circle = document.getElementById("svg"); // Does not work
TweenLite.to(circle, 1, {
  left: "100px"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.5/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div id="html" style="height: 20px;width: 20px;border-radius: 50%;background: tomato;position: absolute"></div>
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle id="svg" cx="10" cy="50" r="10" fill="tomato" />
</svg>
```

<sup>Embed also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8h3atk4/1/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left` is not a valid attribute for SVG elements. GSAP provides an abstraction in which you use the `x` attribute to animate via transforms (both SVG and HTML elments), or you can use the `cx` attribute of SVG circles.

```
TweenLite.to(circle, 1, {
  x: 100
});
```

Or...

```
TweenLite.to(circle, 1, {
  cx: 100
});
```